# magento category page load time is more than2 mins

Tags: category, category-attribute

this is the category view.phtml

```
   <?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        //$_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
?>
<!--<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>-->

    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
        <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("product_finder"); ?>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top_layered_nav"); ?>
    <?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

    <?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>

        <div class="container"><?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?></div>

    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="container"><?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: post `catalog/product/list.phtml` file and are you using swatches on category page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some days ago I am working on speed optimization task on category list page.

I have done all possible way to reduce the execution time but not able achieve this.

after lots of debugging I come to know this is the swatch system that make my page  slow to load.

Then after I start looking to possible ways to solve this issue , and I reach to this file `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php` file

I just solve this issue by rewriting this class file into my module and Rewrite this class one method `attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping(array $parentProducts, $storeId)`

If you don't know how to rewrite helper class in magento please check my this blog.

http://blog.trimantra.com/magento-difference-override-rewrite/

Now moving next what you have to rewrite change in this method. Dont worry I write full new method for you.

```
public function attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping(array $parentProducts, $storeId)
{
    $listSwatchAttr = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productlist')->getSwatchAttribute();

    $parentProductIds = array();
    /* @var $parentProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    foreach ($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
        $parentProductIds[] = $parentProduct->getId();
    }

    $configAttributes = Mage::getResourceModel('configurableswatches/catalog_product_attribute_super_collection')
        ->addParentProductsFilter($parentProductIds)
        ->attachEavAttributes()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ;

    $optionLabels = array();
    foreach ($configAttributes as $attribute) {
        $optionLabels += $attribute->getOptionLabels();
    }

    foreach ($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
        $mapping = array();
        $listSwatchValues = array();

        /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Attribute */
        // normalize to all lower case before we start using them
         **// move this blog at here** 
                $optionLabels = array_map(function ($value) {
                    return array_map('Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey', $value);
                }, $optionLabels);
        foreach ($configAttributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $childProduct Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
            if (!is_array($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts())) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($parentProduct->getChildrenProducts() as $childProduct) {

                // product has no value for attribute, we can't process it
                if (!$childProduct->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    continue;
                }
                $optionId = $childProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());

                // if we don't have a default label, skip it
                if (!isset($optionLabels[$optionId][0])) {
                    continue;
                }

                // normalize to all lower case before we start using them
                /*$optionLabels = array_map(function ($value) {
                    return array_map('Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey', $value);
                }, $optionLabels);*/
                // move this blog at outer foreach loop    
                // using default value as key unless store-specific label is present
                $optionLabel = $optionLabels[$optionId][0];
                if (isset($optionLabels[$optionId][$storeId])) {
                    $optionLabel = $optionLabels[$optionId][$storeId];
                }

                // initialize arrays if not present
                if (!isset($mapping[$optionLabel])) {
                    $mapping[$optionLabel] = array(
                        'product_ids' => array(),
                    );
                }
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['product_ids'][] = $childProduct->getId();
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['label'] = $optionLabel;
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['default_label'] = $optionLabels[$optionId][0];
                $mapping[$optionLabel]['labels'] = $optionLabels[$optionId];

                if ($attribute->getAttributeId() == $listSwatchAttr->getAttributeId()
                    && !in_array($mapping[$optionLabel]['label'], $listSwatchValues)
                ) {
                    $listSwatchValues[$optionId] = $mapping[$optionLabel]['label'];
                }
            } // end looping child products
        } // end looping attributes


        foreach ($mapping as $key => $value) {
            $mapping[$key]['product_ids'] = array_unique($mapping[$key]['product_ids']);
        }

        $parentProduct->setChildAttributeLabelMapping($mapping)
            ->setListSwatchAttrValues($listSwatchValues);
    } // end looping parent products
}
```